# float value for the number of items for each cell in confusion matrix in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, confusion-matrix, azure-machine-learning-service

I work with Azure Machine Learning Service for modeling. To track and analyze the result of a binary classification problem, I use a method named **score-classification** in *azureml.training.tabular.score.scoring* library. I invoke the method like this:

```
metrics = score_classification(
        y_test, y_pred_probs, metrics_names_list, class_labels, train_labels, sample_weight=sample_weights, use_binary=True)
```

Input arguments are:

- *y_test* is an array of 0 and 1.
- *y_pred* is an array of float values for each item.
- *metrics_names_list* is the list of the name of the metrics I want to calculate:['f1_score_classwise', 'confusion_matrix'].
- *class_labels* is a two-item array of [0, 1].
- *train_labels* is a two-item list of ['False', 'True'].

When it calculates the metrics I sent as *metrics_names_list*, the results are shown in the Azure ML portal in the metrics page.

Confusion matrix is one of the metrics I draw each time. It has a combo box for the representation. This combo box could be set as **Raw** to show the number of items for each cell, and **Normalized** to show the percentage of the cells.

The problem is that I see float value instead of integer ones for the Raw configuration of this matrix! I do not know how to handle this issue?
[image]

Comment: What type of number do you expect to see as raw values?

Comment: Absolutely integer values! All the cells of the confusion matrix are integer values because they represent the amount of the TP, TN, FN and FT counts. @Seyfi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sample weights, the confusion matrix values will be calculated as the sum of the sample weights for each cell, which could result in float values. If you want to see integer values in the confusion matrix, you could try not passing any sample weights to the `score_classification` method.

```
classification_metrics = list(constants.CLASSIFICATION_SCALAR_SET)
scores = scoring.score_classification(
            y_test_df.values, predicted, classification_metrics, class_labels, train_labels
        )
```